# unexpected syntax error when changing database - yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii, web-hosting

Recently, I've been trying to move my yii framework website from the localhost to the internet.

I am, however, running into a small error when I try to change the database. Initially the database is set as,

```
'db'=>array(
    'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Kathryn',
    'emulatePrepare' => true,
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
),
```

So, I worked to change it to match the database that I am using with my host (hostgator)

```
'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=stephen_kathryn’,
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => ‘admin’,
        'password' => ‘admin’,
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),
```

When this happens, however, I get an error on the website that says "`syntax error, unexpected 'emulatePrepare' (T_STRING), expecting ')'` in `/home4/stephen/public_html/kathryn/protected/config/main.php on line 73".` 
I've copied and recopied the old code back in and  I continue to get this error.

Is there something simple that I am overlooking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made a type error :

`'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=stephen_kathryn’,`  // use `'` insted of `’`

And the code bellow also the same mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who might have this issue, it stems from using the basic text editor on the mac as opposed to a text editor like sublime. I had to use sublime to edit the file and then reload it in order for it to work.